# Custom authorization in Web API v2

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, identityserver3

My Web API v2 application uses IdentityServer to authorise API requests by checking for a valid bearer token in the request header. This works fine. However for reasons that are beyond my control, there is a new requirement whereby additional authorisation checks need to be performed against a key that will also be sent in the header of each request.

So a request should only be processed by the Web API when both of the following conditions are met:

1. IdentityServer successfully validates the bearer token.
2. The key is successfully validated against a 3rd-party system and has a valid permission set associated with it.

IdentityServer takes care of point 1, using a custom Owin middleware. However I'm not sure where to implement the custom logic described in point 2. This check needs to be performed for every request. A few options that come to mind are:

- Implement a custom Owin middleware, as explained [here](https://dotnetcodr.com/2015/11/16/wiring-up-a-custom-authentication-method-with-owin-in-web-api-part-1-preparation/), which will be invoked in the pipeline after IdentityServer middleware has run.
- Implement a custom authorization filter.
- Implement a custom message handler.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: If this key has to be check for every request a middleware is probably the best place. If its only on some methods the authorisation filter are probably the better idea